# Shell Script that downloads files from S3 folder and also creates folders for them

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3

I wrote a shell script that uses awscli to get files from a few folders in s3. The issues I am having is that when I run the script, it create the folders, but the files are just downloaded in one. the folders that are created are named the same as in S3. How can I modify this script so that the folders are created, but the files are downloaded into their corresponding folder.

```
#!/bin/bash -e


DIRNAME='s3download'
SLASH='/'
SEVENFOLDERS=( "folder1" "folder2" "folder3" "folder4" "folder5" "folder6" "folder7" )
SEVENFOLDERPATH=("s3://blah/folder1/" 
"s3://blah/folder2/" "s3://blah/folder3/" "s3://blah/folder4/" "s3://blah/folder5/" "s3://blah/folder6/" "s3://blah/folder7/" )

mkdir $DIRNAME
for i in "${SEVENFOLDERS[@]}"
do
:
SUBDIR=$DIRNAME$SLASH$i
mkdir -p $SUBDIR
done

for k in "${SEVENFOLDERPATH[@]}"
do
:
SUBDIR=$DIRNAME$SLASH$k
aws s3 cp --recursive $k $SUBDIR
done
echo $i "Status: 200 OK"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aws s3 sync` will download files in the same structure as on S3.

Comment: `aws s3 sync <localfolder> <s3 main bucket (s3://blah/)>` did not work. Can you please elaborate more in code.

Comment: You need to look at the documentation, but I see at least one thing wrong with that command: You need to put the local directory *last*, because the target is always last. Also, "did not work" is not enough information for anyone to help.

Comment: `aws s3 sync <s3 main bucket> .` is taking the S3 dump with its structure intact.

Answer (score 0):

The below command replace the value in the Date node.

```
sed -i -e '/<System>/,/<\/System>/ s|<Date>[0-9a-z:/ .]\{1,\}</Date>|<Date>'"$newDate"'</Date>|g' sample.xml
```